# Let $a \neq 0$ in a field $F$. Determine the integers $n \geq 1$ such that $x+a$ is a factor of $x^n+a^n$

Tags: field-theory

Problem:Let $a \neq 0$ in a field $F$. Determine the integers $n \geq 1$ such that $x+a$ is a factor of $x^n+a^n$.

Attempt: If $n$ is an odd integer, say $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$, then

$x^{2k+1} + a^{2k+1}= (x+a)(x^{2k}-x^{2k-1}a+x^{2k-2}a^2 + ... +x^{2}a^{2k-2}-xa^{2k-1} +a^{2k})$, and so $x+a$ is a factor of 
$x^{2k+1} + a^{2k+1}$.

Now if $n$ is even say $n=2j$, I suspect that $x+a$ is not a factor of $x^n+a^n$, but I am not sure how to show this is true. Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x+a$ is a factor of a polynomial $P(x)$ if and only if $P(-a)=0$.

If $P(x)=x^n+a^n$, then $P(-a)=(-a)^n+a^n$ which is zero for odd $n$, and for even $n$ it is $2a^n$. Can that be zero?

Comment: Not unless $a$ is $0$ cause fields are integral domains. Ok thank you that seems so obvious now, ugh.

Comment: Ah, but there are fields of characteristic two. @IntegrateThis

Comment: Wait, so if the field has characteristic $2$, how would you factor $x^n+a^n$ in the even case ? Sorry now I am even more confused lol.

Comment: @IntegrateThis If $\mathrm{char}F=2$, then $(x+a)^2=x^2+2ax+a^2=x^2+a^2$. ;-) More generally, for $\mathrm{char}F=p$, $(x+a)^p=x^p+a^p$. It's called Freshman's dream if I'm not mistaken and it shows that $x \mapsto x^p$ is a ring homomorphism when  $\mathrm{char}F=p$.

Comment: Ok! I've seen this proof actually but I forgot to apply it here. You seem to be answering all my questions @stressedout.

Comment: @IntegrateThis Yeah. You ask questions that are within my current knowledge of algebra. :P And your questions aren't trivial like prove that $G/H$ is a group iff $H$ is normal in $G$ or things like that.